# Генерируемый SQL-запрос

Tags: python, sql

уважаемые пользователи. Подскажите ответ на вопрос, необходимо сформировать SELECT запрос в БД, данные для которого предоставляют несколько QCheckBoxe's(PyQt5) в виде кортежей, загвоздка заключается в том, что если  пользователь не выбрал несколько чекбоксов в определенной группе, то  в IN попадает пустой кортеж, что вызывает исключение, а по задумке, должно выбираться всё по текущему столбцу, как можно иначе сформировать запрос, чтобы выбрать нужные данные?
Сам запрос:

```
"""SELECT subranges.subrange, ranges.range,
          family, name, surname,
          departments.department, locations.location, defaultStatus
   FROM members
   INNER JOIN ranges on members.range = ranges.id
   INNER JOIN departments on members.department = departments.id
   INNER JOIN subranges on members.subrange = subranges.id
   INNER JOIN locations on members.defaultLocation = locations.id
   WHERE members.range IN {0}
   AND deparments.departmen IN {1}
   AND surname = '{2}'""".format(someTuple1, someTuple2, someString1)
```

Comment: *в IN попадает пустой кортеж* Кортежи - это на стороне питона. А проблема выявляется на стороне MySQL - так что же именно попадает туда?

Comment: Если смотреть уже форматированный запрос, то при не выбранных чекбоксах будет, для примера "....WHERE members.range IN () AND deparments.departmen IN ('someDepartments1', 'someDepartments2')"

Comment: Формируйте запрос частями, дописывая к нему только текст требуемых условий

Comment: *Если смотреть уже форматированный запрос ... `... WHERE members.range IN () AND ...`* - вот даже просто кавычек не добавлено, типа `... WHERE members.range IN ('') AND ...`? мда, я  был лучшего мнения о питоне - это просто обязано квалифицироваться как баг.